# Migrated questions are shown as {closed} on user profile pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, migrated-marker

Migrated questions are shown as *closed* on a user's profile.

---

In the [question list](https://meta.superuser.com/questions):

> [image]

On the [user profile](https://meta.superuser.com/users/22317/daniel-beck?tab=questions):

> [image]

---

This affects both meta and main sites and is inconsistent and confusing.

Comment: Technically they are closed on the original site

Comment: @ivo true. But both lists are from the same site, and show a different thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good find - this will be fixed in the next build (> rev 2012.2.10.1007).

Comment: Change is in rev 2012.2.13.1046. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be important, How would a User who just arrived here, view that?  What would they think? And will they proceed to the question that has been migrated, or just bail out thinking they got shut down completely again?

Getting A Quick average of the user showing up again, at the migration location, after it was migrated, should be able to determine if this is often the End of thier participation, or the beginning of getting answers in the right location.